# How to change the message "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." on IIS error 500"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I'm trying to specify a custom error page to 500 `IIS` error code, I have following code.

**config:**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <clear/>
  <error
    statusCode="500"
    path="/Views/Error/page500.html"
    responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

My html page500 file is in this route: `/Views/Error/page500.html`, I'm using sitecore CMS, then I trigger an error 500 turning off the `DataBase` engine, then my web crashes with a 500 internal server error but instead of show `page500.htm`l.
The Error message:

> "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred." on `IIS` error 500" is showed.

I dont understand why, I need `page500.html` showed when 500 code `IIS` is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The error you specified(500 internal server error) is triggered by asp.net runtime. For that u need to add custom errors as below:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="/Views/Error/page500.aspx" mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Views/Error/page500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

Make sure it is an .aspx or .cshtml page but not html, as IIS has a bug detailing with .html pages.

I have a blog post written on this topic that might help you for more info [Handling 500 errors in Sitecore 8, 7, 6](http://sitecoreblog.tools4geeks.com/Blog/48/Dealing-with-500-errors-in-Sitecore-8,7,6)